# OnEdit / OnFocus Hook or Similar in Bespin Embedded?

Tags: javascript, bespin

I'm trying to implement a hook when text is edited in a bespin embedded instance.  Ideally, I'd simply like to know when the instance has gained or lost focus to capture the user action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure when you last checked out bespin but in the newer releases there is a textChanged event you can subscribe to:

```
editor.textChanged .add(function((oldRange, newRange, newText)) {
    console.log('textChanged', JSON.stringify(newText));
});
```